# 合計値を求めたい

Tags: java

**やりたいこと**
引数　20092812345　→　2001441678522 としたい。

```
20092812345 * { 1, 3, 7, 9, 7, 3, 1, 3, 9, 7, 1 } = 2(2*1) , 0(0*3), 0(0*7), 81(9*9), 14(2*7), 24(8*3), 1(1*1),
6(2*3), 27(3*9), 28(4*7),5(5*1)
```

↓

```
2 + 0 + 0 + 81 + 14 + 24 + 1 + 6 + 27 + 28 +5 = 188
```

188 →　百の位は無視する。
十の位はマイナス１０する。
一の位はマイナス１０する。

```
class nouNum {
    public  String Num01(String in){
        char[] out = in.toCharArray();
        int[] mul = { 1, 3, 7, 9, 7, 3, 1, 3, 9, 7, 1 };
        int n = Math.min(out.length, 11);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            out[i] = (char)((out[i] - '0') * mul[i] % 10 + '0');
        return new String(out);
    }
}

package test;

public class test01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        nouNum test01 = new nouNum();
        System.out.println(test01.Num01("20092812345"));
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

public class test01 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Num01("20092812345"));
  }

  static String Num01(String in){
    int[] out = in.chars().map(c -> c-'0').toArray();
    int[] mul = { 1, 3, 7, 9, 7, 3, 1, 3, 9, 7, 1 };
    int n = Math.min(out.length, mul.length);
    int r, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      sum += (r = out[i] * mul[i]);
      out[i] = r % 10;
    }

    return IntStream.of(out)
      .mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(joining(""))
      + (110 - sum % 100);
  }
}
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/295020

Comment: 「188 →　百の位は無視する。十の位はマイナス10する。一の位はマイナス10する。」を数式化(?)するとなれば、`(110 - 188 % 100)` でしょうかね。この計算結果(?)を文字列に変換して `20014416785` に連結する、と。

Comment: (110 - 188 % 100)　これは1の位のみ求める式でしょうか？

Comment: いえ、`2001441678522` の末尾にある `22` を求める式です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。(110 - 188 % 100)こちらはコードにすると、out[i]　％10 ということでしょうか？

Comment: @iuy 回答にしてみましたので参考にして下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

何のためのコードなのかが不明なので、少なくとも

> やりたいこと
> 引数　20092812345　→　2001441678522 としたい。
> 　　　　　:
>
> 188 →
> 百の位は無視する。十の位はマイナス１０する。一の位はマイナス１０する。

の場合には想定通りに動作する Java コードの一例です。

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

public class test01 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Num01("20092812345", "13797313971"));
  }

  static String Num01(String in, String ml){
    int[] out = in.chars().map(c -> c-'0').toArray();
    int[] mul = ml.chars().map(c -> c-'0').toArray();
    int n = Math.min(out.length, mul.length);
    int r, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      sum += (r = out[i] * mul[i]);
      out[i] = r % 10;
    }

    return IntStream.of(out)
      .mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(joining(""))
      + (110 - sum % 100);
  }
}

// =>
2001441678522
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！すいません、わからないことがあるのですが、(110 - sum % 100)の１１０という数字はなぜ１１０なのでしょうか？

Comment: 「十の位はマイナス１０する。一の位はマイナス１０。」を計算式に置き換えると `(-10*10 - 10*1) = -110` になるから、です。

Comment: ありがとうございます！あの、(c -> c-'0')こちらのｃは変数宣言ないのですが、こちらは何の値か教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 文字列 "20092812345" や "13797313971" を構成している文字(`char`型変数)になります。`(c -> c-'0')` は無名関数/ラムダ式(`lambda expression`)で、`char lambda(char c) { return c-'0'; }` に相当します。

Comment: ありがとうございます！頂いたコードを少し変更してみたところ、out[i] = r % 10;の"i"のところでエラー→"i"を変数に解決できませんと出てしまいまして、for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)で変数宣言があるのにこちらのエラーが出てしまう理由がわからないのですが、もうしわけありませんが、教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: こちらの環境は `Java full version "1.8.0_201-b09"` なのですが、質問欄に追記されたコードをコンパイル・実行する事ができました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！ということはこちらの環境がいけないということなんですね！頂いたコードは実行できましたが、私が変更したコードだとなぜか実行ができませんでした。すいません、ありがとうございます！！